# Spark sql query causing huge data shuffle read / write

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using spark sql for processing the data. Here is the query

```
select 
    /*+ BROADCAST (C) */ A.party_id, 
    IF(B.master_id is NOT NULL, B.master_id, 'MISSING_LINK') as master_id, 
    B.is_matched, 
    D.partner_name, 
    A.partner_id, 
    A.event_time_utc, 
    A.funnel_stage_type, 
    A.product_id_set, 
    A.ip_address, 
    A.session_id, 
    A.tdm_retailer_id, 
    C.product_name ,
    CASE WHEN C.product_category_lvl_01 is NULL THEN 'OUTOFSALE' ELSE product_category_lvl_01 END as product_category_lvl_01,
    CASE WHEN C.product_category_lvl_02 is NULL THEN 'OUTOFSALE' ELSE product_category_lvl_02 END as product_category_lvl_02,
    CASE WHEN C.product_category_lvl_03 is NULL THEN 'OUTOFSALE' ELSE product_category_lvl_03 END as product_category_lvl_03,
    CASE WHEN C.product_category_lvl_04 is NULL THEN 'OUTOFSALE' ELSE product_category_lvl_04 END as product_category_lvl_04, 
    C.brand_name 
from 
    browser_data A 
    INNER JOIN (select partner_name, partner_alias_tdm_id as npa_retailer_id from npa_retailer) D  
        ON (A.tdm_retailer_id = D.npa_retailer_id) 
    LEFT JOIN 
        (identity as B1 INNER JOIN (select random_val from random_distribution) B2) as B 
        ON (A.party_id = B.party_id and A.random_val = B.random_val) 
    LEFT JOIN product_taxonomy as C 
        ON (A.product_id = C.product_id and D.npa_retailer_id = C.retailer_id)
```

Where,
browser_data A  - Its around 110 GB data with 519 million records,

D - Small dataset which maps to only one value in A. As this is small spark sql automatically broadcast it (confirmed in the execution plan in explain)

B - 5 GB with 45 million records contains only 3 columns. This dataset is replicated 30 times (done with cartesian product with dataset which contains 0 to 29 values) so that skewed key (lot of data against one in dataset A) issue is solved.This will result in 150 GB of data.

C - 900 MB with 9 million records. This is joined with A with broadcast join (so no shuffle)

Above query works well. But when I see spark UI I can observe above query triggers shuffle read of 6.8 TB. As dataset D and C are joined as broadcast it wont cause any shuffle. So only join of A and B should cause the shuffle. Even if we consider all data shuffled read then it should be limited to 110 GB (A) + 150 GB (B) = 260 GB. Why it is triggering 6.8 TB of shuffle read and 40 GB of shuffle write.
Any help appreciated. Thank you in advance

Thank you

Manish

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would do is use `DataFrame.explain` on it.  That will show you the execution plan so you can see exactly what is actually happen.  I would check the output to confirm that the Broadcast Join is really happening.  Spark has a setting to control how big your data can be before it gives up on doing a broadcast join.

I would also note that your INNER JOIN against the random_distribution looks suspect.  I may have recreated your schema wrong, but when I did explain I got this:

```
scala> spark.sql(sql).explain
== Physical Plan ==
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Detected cartesian product for INNER join between logical plans
LocalRelation [party_id#99]
and
LocalRelation [random_val#117]
Join condition is missing or trivial.
Use the CROSS JOIN syntax to allow cartesian products between these relations.;
```

Finally, is your input data compressed?  You may be seeing the size differences because of a combination of no your data no longer being compressed, and because of the way it is being serialized.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I confirmed that broadcast join is happening for dataset C and D. I am using AVRO formatted data which uses snappy compressor.