# Exception with Join and withColumn in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, join, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to join the following 2 dataframes:

```
val df1 = Seq(
      ("Verizon", "USA"),
      ("AT & T", "PK"),
      ("Verizon", "IND")
    ).toDF("Brand", "Country")

    val df2 = Seq(
      (8, "USA"),
      (64, "UK"),
      (-27, "DE")
    ).toDF("TS", "Country")
```

If I join like this, it worked:

```
df1.join(df2, Seq("Country")).count
```

But when I try to use **withColumn()** and **lit()** before join (to replace the column values), it throws an exception:

```
df1.withColumn("Country", lit("USA")).join(df2, Seq("Country")).count
```

**Exception:**

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Detected implicit cartesian product for INNER join between logical plans
LocalRelation
and
Project
+- Filter (isnotnull(_2#680) && (USA = _2#680))
   +- LocalRelation [_1#679, _2#680]
Join condition is missing or trivial.
Either: use the CROSS JOIN syntax to allow cartesian products between these
relations, or: enable implicit cartesian products by setting the configuration
variable spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled=true;
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.CheckCartesianProducts$$anonfun$apply$21.applyOrElse(Optimizer.scala:1124)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.CheckCartesianProducts$$anonfun$apply$21.applyOrElse(Optimizer.scala:1121)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$2.apply(TreeNode.scala:267)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$2.apply(TreeNode.scala:267)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:70)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:266)
   ...
```

It also works when I use `crossjoin`:

```
df1.withColumn("Country", lit("USA")).crossJoin(df2.filter(col("Country") === "USA"))
```

But I don't understand why it is not working with simple **join**. why do I need to use **cross join** to make it work. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detected cartesian product for INNER join on literal column in PySpark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53449100/detected-cartesian-product-for-inner-join-on-literal-column-in-pyspark)

Comment: That one is related to sort merge join. It isn't.

Comment: Setting `sql("set spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled=true")` before doing the join worked for me. But don't know why it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

Spark analyzer detected cross join condition when you are intended to use inner join.

Since cross join is costly so default behavior to throw exception when Physical plan detects Cross join state where query didn't used cross join explicitly.

This is happening due to replaced column formed from literal.

[Cross join behavior explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50967218/spark-sql-query-causing-huge-data-shuffle-read-write?rq=1) is explained in more details in thread that  user10465355 mentioned.

Comment: That is my question that why I am getting the cross join excetpion. What is the reason for that?

Comment: This is happening due to replaced column formed from literal 'USA' . So if you do inner join using column that is formed from this type column you will hit this exception. This is simple rule validation in analyzer

Comment: So you mean to say, dataframe with lit column doesn't work with join? If yes, then what is the correct way to have join with lit without using cross join as it is expensive operation.

Comment: It is expensive so if you still want to use it. Use using crosjoin syntax. Based on our use case if we have to do cross join, we do using crossjoin so analyzer know that you are intended to use crossjoin and will not complain.

Comment: But I don't want to use cross join. Is there any otherway to solve this problem?

Comment: If one column has the same value and it is the key column to be joined. Does spark imagine that it is cross join?

Comment: Yes, it will always be cross join since all rows are same value in column that used for join.

Comment: Now, i got it. Thanks!